# Synchronized on instance object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a service method which is basically inserting a record into database. What I am trying to achieve is to block a piece of code based on an object or it's variable.

I need to block others threads based on this id: `rcvTransactionRequest.getPoDistributionId()` 
I do not want to block all threads which are coming into this method. In the end, I am trying to validate receivable quantity that should not be exceeded which may happen if multiple threads enter the critical secion.

```
    PoDistPayload poDistPayload = poDistService.getPoDist(rcvTransactionRequest.getPoDistributionId());
    synchronized (poDistPayload) {
        if (!poDistService.isReceivable(poDistPayload, rcvTransactionRequest.getQuantity()))
            throw ebsExceptionFactory.build(1036L, rcvTransactionRequest.getQuantity(), poDistPayload.getReceivableQuantity());

        PoDistRcv poDistRcv = PoDistRcv.of(rcvTransactionRequest);
        poDistRcv.setStatus(Status.TRANSACTION_STARTED);
        poDistRcv = poDistRcvRepository.save(poDistRcv);
        return new BaseTransactionResponse(poDistRcv.getTransactionId(), serialCountPerRequest, poDistRcv.getStatus());
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to allow only one thread into the critical section based on the value of `distributionId`. not the object instance?

Comment: Basically yes but I think it shouldn't matter since that object has also distributionId field which is used in equals and hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ConcurrentMap to implement a simple locking scheme:

```
Object newLock=new Object();
Object existingLock;
// Wait until this thread can acquire lock
synchronized(newLock) {
  do {
    existingLock=cMap.putIfAbsent(distributionId,newLock);
    if(existingLock!=null) {
        // Locked by another thread. You can fail immediately, or wait until the lock is released
        synchronized(existingLock) {
          // Need timeout here because lock holder may notify before we wait
          existingLock.wait(timeout);
       }
    }
  } while(existingLock!=null);
  // You have the lock
  // Do work
  // Unlock and notify
  cMap.remove(distributionId,newLock);
  newLock.notify();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I got the idea but I decided to use Guava Strip which I guess use similar logic with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using guava strip.